# root権限で git flow が実行できない

Tags: git, git-flow

今awsのec2(amazon linux)で開発しています。
git flowをインストールし、初期ユーザーであるec2-userではgit flowコマンドが叩けるのですが、root権限でコマンドを叩くと"Command not found"となってしまいます。
どうしてでしょうか。

ec2-user でも、 root でも `which git` は　`/usr/bin/git` です。

Comment: 一般ユーザと root で PATH の設定が異なっているためだと思われます。

Comment: git コマンドが見えないのか、git の flow サブコマンドが見えないのか切り分けできますか？

Comment: git コマンドが見えてない前提で root と ec2-user の両方で `which git` としてみるといろいろわかるでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ec2-userで`which git`をすると、
`/usr/bin/git`となります。
また、rootで`which git`をすると、
/usr/bin/gitとなります。
との結果になりました。
補足ですが、
ec2-userで`which sudo`をすると
`/usr/bin/sudo`となり、
rootで`which sudo`とすると、
/usr/bin/sudoとなります。

Comment: /usr/bin/git が存在していて実行できないのか、それとも `git status` は実行できるが `git flow` が実行できないのか、どっちなのか現状の質問文からでは判断できません。どうログインして、どのようなコマンドを入力して、どのような結果が得られたのか、一切省略せずに正確に書き込んでください。

Answer (score 2):

git コマンドは、 `git SOMECOMMAND` を実行した時、それが git 自身のコマンドでなかった場合には、 `git-SOMECOMMAND` の実行ファイルをパスから探しに行きます。なので、今回のケースだと、`git-flow` が root のパスに入っていない場所にインストールされているのでは、と思っています。